# How do you print a string in reverse using a For loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, slice

I'm trying to print the string "hello" in reverse using a For loop, the result should be "olleh". However, I'm having trouble removing the last character in the string after it has been pushed to the array. As a result, it just prints the last letter of the string.

How can I update this code so that the loop removes the last character in the string after pushing it to the array?

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let holder = [];

  for (let i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    holder.push(str.charAt(str.length - 1));
    str.slice(0, -1);
  }

  return holder;
}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `i-1` instead of `str.length-1`. `i` will traverse all the characters in the string. Slice is a slow method, so avoid using it until you have no other way

```js
function reverseString(str) {

  let holder = [];

  for (let i = str.length; i > 0; i--) {
    holder.push(str.charAt(i - 1));

  }

  return holder;
}

console.log(reverseString("hello").join(''));
```

Answer (score 3):

[String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

> The `slice()` method extracts a section of a string and ***returns it as a new string***, without modifying the original string.

You have to store the ***returned*** string back to the variable:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  let holder = [];
  for (let i = str.length; i > 0; i--){
    holder.push(str.charAt(str.length -1));
    str = str.slice(0, -1); // update the variable
  }
  return holder.join(''); // join them to return the string
}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Though you can simply split and reverse like the following way:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and smallest way to do this would be combining 3 methods altogether:

```js
function reverseString(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
console.log(reverseString("hello"));
```

Comment: Op was wanting to use a for loop.

Comment: OP wants reversed string in `holder` array like `[o,l,l,e,h]`

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that using for loop was compulsory for him so i suggested simple way

Comment: Except he did in the title of the question. Not saying your answer is a wrong way to  reverse a string, it is a go to for me If I need to.

Answer (score -1):

Combine a for of loop and a split('') and you can just split up the word and add each character to the start of the array.

```js
let word = 'hello';
let holder = [];
for(let char of word.split('')) {
  // Add to start of array
  holder.unshift(char);
}
console.log(holder.join(''));
```

Comment: OP wants reversed string in `holder` array like `[o,l,l,e,h]`

Comment: Updated, but same diff, just add to the start of an array instead of the string.